# Cannot mint ERC223 token

Tags: solidity, erc-223

Hello I have a simple implementation for a ERC223 Token. I use this repository: [ERC223-token-standard](https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard)

Here is my contract Code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

import "./ERC223-token-standard-development/token/ERC223/ERC223Burnable.sol";
import "./ERC223-token-standard-development/token/ERC223/ERC223Mintable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC223Burnable, ERC223Mintable{
}
```

The first strange Thing is that I get this warning when compiling:

```
Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to view
    function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyMinter returns (bool) {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

I think this is weird because to my understanding it changes the state of the contract and should not be a view function

However after creating my contract and using the `mint` function the totalSupply is still 0 even though `isMinter(myaddr)` returns `true`. I thought that I was just doing something wrong in the truffle testfile but after I pushed my code into Remix I still get the same warning and the total supply is still 0.

I hope you can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `mint` is wrong

```
function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyMinter returns (bool) {
    _totalSupply.add(amount);
    balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
    return true;
}
```

It should be

```
function mint(address account, uint256 amount) public onlyMinter returns (bool) {
    bytes memory empty = hex"00000000";
    _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(amount);
    emit Transfer(address(0x0), msg.sender, amount, empty);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But isnt this the official ERC223 implementation. how could this be wrong? I wonder what else is wrong with this Code.

Comment: The key part to note is that `_totalSupply.add(amount)` doesn't do anything. It just adds two numbers and returns the result. `_totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount)` actually changes the value of `_totalSupply`. (Same thing for `balances[msg.sender].)

Comment: Yes thank you I understand. It works now but I still get the warning.

Comment: You have to note that ERC223 has never gained much traction. Some of the functionality is provided now by [ERC777](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-777).